# How to defer execution of IEnumerable-returning function that begins a LINQ expression?

Tags: c#, linq

Suppose I have something like this:

```
IEnumerable<T> result = BuildAList<T>()
   // lots of LINQ operators
   ;
```

But maybe `BuildAList` is expensive, and I don't want to call it unless and until someone actually starts iterating over `result`. Is there a simple, idiomatic way to do this?

(I can obviously write my own `IEnumerable<T>` class, but I'm hoping there's a way to do it with the existing operators etc.)

Comment: Doesn't IEnumerable work that way anyway? I mean not iterate the whole thing by default? Or is the expensive part at the beginning before the start of iteration?

Comment: @Timbo. Correct; `BuildAList<T>` returns `List<T>`, but it's expensive to call it. So the trick is to defer calling it until one of the downstream operators needs the result.

Comment: That's the default behavior of IEnumerable<T>, it is deferred until and unless allocated, which need to be only when required. Only things is beware that even network call to database will be deferred.

Comment: @MrinalKamboj Right, but `BuildAList()` will be called immediately; that's what I'm hoping to avoid.

Comment: And you can't change BuildAList to not... build a List?

Comment: @Timbo For the sake of the question, let's say no :)

Comment: @dlf then for IEnumerable processing you are in a tricky situation, you have  to just avoid any allocation except the very end, deal only with IEnumerable, till the point allocation can be made. Otherwise once you call for allocation, there's no way to stop it. Yield, may help to stream data. It needs to be your custom code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm afraid currently there is no standard method for doing that, so you have to roll your own. It cannot be extension method, so should be regular static method with iterator block (using `yield return`) and factory delegate similar to `Lazy<T>` which will ensure the desired deferred execution.

Something like this:

```
public static class Iterators
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> Lazy<T>(Func<IEnumerable<T>> factory)
    {
        foreach (var item in factory())
            yield return item;
    }
}
```

And use it as follows:

```
var result = Iterators.Lazy(() => BuildAList<T>());
// lots of LINQ operators
;
```

**Edit:** The downside of the above implementation is that the factory method will be invoked for each execution of the returned enumerable. It can be avoided by combining the implementation with `Lazy<T>` class:

```
public static class Iterators
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> Lazy<T>(Func<IEnumerable<T>> factory)
    {
        return LazyIterator(new Lazy<IEnumerable<T>>(factory));
    }

    private static IEnumerable<T> LazyIterator<T>(Lazy<IEnumerable<T>> source)
    {
        foreach (var item in source.Value)
            yield return item;
    }
}
```

Comment: I was afraid of that, but I suppose this solution doesn't require *that* much effort

Comment: @Ivan is this solution similar to data streaming, which will fetch the records one by one from the source using Yield, then using a foreach loop I can keep adding it to a Cache, so it will keep getting filled in the Background, and every-time Cache is accessed data can be seen filling up

Comment: @dlf Its not difficult to get `IEnumerable<T>`, lot of systems offer it, like database ORM, its about when to allocate and use it

Comment: @MrinalKamboj Not sure I follow. Here the iterator method is used **only** to get easy deferred execution implementation of the factory method.

Comment: @Ivan let's assume, I fetch IEnumerable<T> as a result of database query, now I want this data to stream and fill a Cache as I enumerate at the caller / business layer. SIGNALR informs Ui about data update in Cache, every 10K rows, for total million records. Then in my view, I need a Lazy iteration like this, simple yield would not help. I am not sure how much clear I am now, but this is our real use case

Answer (score 1):

use this model generic method:

```
public virtual IList<T> GetList(Func<T, bool> where,
         params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] navigationProperties)
    {
        List<T> list;
        using (var context = new DbEntities())
        {
            IQueryable<T> dbQuery = context.Set<T>();

            //Apply eager loading
            foreach (Expression<Func<T, object>> navigationProperty in navigationProperties)
                dbQuery = dbQuery.Include<T, object>(navigationProperty);

            list = dbQuery
                .AsNoTracking()
                .Where(where)
                .ToList<T>();
        }
        return list;
    }
```

Comment: Where is it mentioned that EF is used

Comment: yes its used EF but for Enumartor Generic only u can use this :

Answer (score 1):

You could make result into a lazy property and have the downstream stuff reference that.

```
class MyClass<T>
{
    IEnumerable<T> result; 

    IEnumerable<T> Result
    {
        get { return result ?? (result = BuildAList()); }
    }

    List<T> BuildAList()
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: Something along these lines would work (my tentative solution derives from `IEnumerable<T>` and performs the lazy operation in `GetEnumerator()`), but I was hoping it could be done with less effort. I guess I'm lazy too.